# Combining LD matrix plot with SNP and gene data with ggplot / ggbio tracks() function

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bioconductor

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to plot the linkage disequilibrium (LD) in a certain genomic region in a similar way as this website does: https://analysistools.nci.nih.gov/LDlink/?tab=ldmatrix. The problem is that the figure from this website has a low quality and I need the figure for publication purposes. All the sample files I have used are at the end of the post so that you can reproduce my code.

This is what I have done so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(scales)
library(ggbio)
library(GenomicRanges)
library(Homo.sapiens)
library(rtracklayer)
library(GenomicRanges)
library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19)
library(VariantAnnotation)
source("bed2granges.R")
data(hg19IdeogramCyto, package = "biovizBase")
data(hg19Ideogram, package = "biovizBase")
data(genesymbol, package = "biovizBase")
hg19 <- keepSeqlevels(hg19IdeogramCyto, paste0("chr", c(1:22, "X", "Y")))
```

I downloaded the matrix txt file from the LDlink website to use it for my LD plot. I melted the dataframe to obtain the grading colors:

```
# FIRST PLOT - LD plot for CEU population

#Load r-squared values in Table format
CEU_plot<- read.table("r2_SOD1_matrix.txt", header = TRUE)

#Load chromosomal positions for each rs ID
RS_location <- read.table("SOD1_SNPs.bed", header = FALSE)

#Melt table to be able to make a gradient
CEU_plot_m <- melt(CEU_plot)

# x-axis values - chromosomal position
CEU_plot_m$RS_number <- factor(RS_location[,2], levels = RS_location[,2])

# y-axis - variable
CEU_plot_m$variable <- factor(CEU_plot_m$variable, levels = sort(CEU_plot_m$variable, decreasing = TRUE))

CEU = ggplot(CEU_plot_m, aes(x = RS_number, y = variable)) +
        labs (title = "r2 plot for SOD1 gene in CEU population ",
              x = element_blank (),
              y = "rs IDs") +
        theme(text = element_text(size=8),
              axis.text.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0)) +
        geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "white" ,high = "red")
CEU
```

Then I use ggbio package to generate the third and fourth track of my final plot

```
# DATA FOR REST OF PLOTS
wh <- genesymbol[c("SOD1")]
chr_name <- as.vector(slot(wh@seqnames,"values"))
chr_start <- slot(wh@ranges, "start") + 0 - 2000
chr_end <- slot (wh@ranges, "start") + slot (wh@ranges, "width") - 1 + 2000
gene_name <- slot(wh@ranges, "NAMES")

#THIRD PLOT - SOD1 SNPs
SNP <- bed_to_granges("SOD1_SNPs.bed")
SNP_chr <- slot(SNP@seqnames,"values")
if (chr_name %in% SNP_chr) {
        seqlengths(SNP) <- seqlengths(hg19Ideogram)[names(seqlengths(SNP))]
        SNP_dn <- keepSeqlevels(unique(SNP), chr_name)
}

SNPs_plot <-  autoplot(SNP_dn,  xlab = chr_name) +
        guides (colour = TRUE) +
        theme_bw()+
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.border = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_blank()) +
        theme(legend.position="none") +
        scale_color_manual(values = score <- c("black")) +
        scale_fill_manual (breaks = score <- c("2"),
                           values= score <- c("black"),
                           name = "Variant type",
                           labels = expression(bold(SNP))) +
        xlim(chr_start,chr_end) +
        scale_x_sequnit("Mb")
fixed(SNP_IDs) <- TRUE
SNPs_plot

##FOURTH PLOT - SOD1 gene
GENES_plot <-   autoplot(Homo.sapiens, which = wh, layout = "linear",  xlab = chr_name) +
        guides (colour = FALSE) +
        xlim(chr_start,chr_end) +
        scale_x_sequnit("Mb")
fixed(GENES_plot) <- TRUE
GENES_plot

# Main tracks plot title
plot_title <- as.expression(bquote('Variation in'~italic(.(gene_name))~'gene'))

# X axis scale according to gene start and gene end
scale_combined <- GRanges(chr_name, IRanges(start = chr_start, end = chr_end))

# Combination of SNPs plot with Genes plot

Gene_SNPs <-     tracks(SNPs = SNP_IDs,
                    Genes=GENES_plot,
                    heights = c(0.5,2.0),
                    xlim = scale_combined,
                    xlab = paste("\n",chr_name,"\n"),
                    title = plot_title,
                    label.bg.fill = "grey60") +
                    scale_x_sequnit("Mb")
Gene_SNPs
```

The problem comes when I want to combine the CEU plot (first track) with the SNPs (third track) and the Gene (fourth track) plots. I need to combine a ggplot list (CEU) with two GGBio objects (SNPs_plot and GENES_plot). On top of that I would like to generate an additional track between the LD plot and the SNPs_plot that links the discrete values of the x axis from the CEU plot with the SNPs located in a continuous scale from the SNPs_plot.

In summary, this is what I have:

LD Plot:
[image: LD Plot]
Combined SNPs data with Gene track:
[image: SNP and Gene data]
An this is the final combined plot that I want:
[image: Final]

These are the original files I'm using:

'r2_SOD1_matrix.txt' input file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B34ok3wh5PjTMklhNzBrT3JoM0k

'SOD1_SNPs.bed' input file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B34ok3wh5PjTaGx6QWdZd3pmbUE

'bed2granges.R' function

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B34ok3wh5PjTMHNFa1pod0liYzA

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] scales_0.4.1                            reshape_0.8.6                          
 [3] VariantAnnotation_1.20.2                Rsamtools_1.26.1                       
 [5] SummarizedExperiment_1.4.0              BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19_1.4.0      
 [7] BSgenome_1.42.0                         Biostrings_2.42.1                      
 [9] XVector_0.14.0                          rtracklayer_1.34.1                     
[11] Homo.sapiens_1.3.1                      TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene_3.2.2
[13] org.Hs.eg.db_3.4.0                      GO.db_3.4.0                            
[15] OrganismDbi_1.16.0                      GenomicFeatures_1.26.2                 
[17] AnnotationDbi_1.36.1                    Biobase_2.34.0                         
[19] GenomicRanges_1.26.2                    GenomeInfoDb_1.10.2                    
[21] IRanges_2.8.1                           S4Vectors_0.12.1                       
[23] ggbio_1.22.3                            BiocGenerics_0.20.0                    
[25] ggplot2_2.2.1                          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1                    AnnotationHub_2.6.4          
 [3] splines_3.3.2                 Formula_1.2-1                
 [5] shiny_1.0.0                   assertthat_0.1               
 [7] interactiveDisplayBase_1.12.0 latticeExtra_0.6-28          
 [9] RBGL_1.50.0                   yaml_2.1.14                  
[11] RSQLite_1.1-2                 backports_1.0.5              
[13] lattice_0.20-34               biovizBase_1.22.0            
[15] digest_0.6.11                 RColorBrewer_1.1-2           
[17] checkmate_1.8.2               colorspace_1.3-2             
[19] htmltools_0.3.5               httpuv_1.3.3                 
[21] Matrix_1.2-8                  plyr_1.8.4                   
[23] XML_3.98-1.5                  biomaRt_2.30.0               
[25] zlibbioc_1.20.0               xtable_1.8-2                 
[27] BiocParallel_1.8.1            htmlTable_1.8                
[29] tibble_1.2                    nnet_7.3-12                  
[31] lazyeval_0.2.0                survival_2.40-1              
[33] magrittr_1.5                  mime_0.5                     
[35] memoise_1.0.0                 GGally_1.3.0                 
[37] foreign_0.8-67                graph_1.52.0                 
[39] BiocInstaller_1.24.0          tools_3.3.2                  
[41] data.table_1.10.0             stringr_1.1.0                
[43] munsell_0.4.3                 cluster_2.0.5                
[45] ensembldb_1.6.2               grid_3.3.2                   
[47] RCurl_1.95-4.8                dichromat_2.0-0              
[49] labeling_0.3                  bitops_1.0-6                 
[51] base64enc_0.1-3               gtable_0.2.0                 
[53] DBI_0.5-1                     reshape2_1.4.2               
[55] R6_2.2.0                      GenomicAlignments_1.10.0     
[57] gridExtra_2.2.1               knitr_1.15.1                 
[59] Hmisc_4.0-2                   stringi_1.1.2                
[61] Rcpp_0.12.9                   rpart_4.1-10                 
[63] acepack_1.4.1
```